# What is the Monster Name?

Tags: word

There is a world which is full of monsters and everything they hear is inverted (i.e. If you say "*Moob*" they will hear "*Boom*")

There is a Treasure Chest and it is Locked. In order to unlock you need to kill the Monster nicknamed "SAP" with his sons the 5 Dark Elves Archers every Dark Elves is Carrying  "SAP" name (1 Letter each Dark Elves).

In order to defeat "SAP" he must hear his Name

 If you kill the Dark Elves Archers you will receive a "SWORD"

What is the Monster Name?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by "everything they hear is inverted"?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, and congratulations on your first puzzle here. Do take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with the site.

Comment: If you say Moob they will hear "Boom"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the Monster's name is

> Password

Because

> The Monster's inverted nickname is `Pas` and if you combine that with the `sword` you get `Password`

Comment: It seems that the 5 Elves carry "SAP" name, so imo it can't be longer than 5 characters. "SAP" is just a nickname and not a part of the name.

Answer (score 3):

Since @Swit's answer has not been accepted, yet,  I'll throw out an alternative.
I think the monster's name might be

> Deadrows

Because

> Take the acronym of the **D**ark **E**lves **A**rchers and then reverse the "SWORD" to get drows and append that to the DEA from the acronym to get Deadrows.